# Jest, expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

Testing lifecycle methods when a VueJS component renders on the transition group.

I've been writing tests for lifecycle methods when the component renders on the transition group of the following VueJS component I've made little progress on getting it to work and would appreciate advice regarding this. I also tried switching between shallow mounting and mounting the component though that seemed to make no difference.

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import StaggeredTransition from '../src/index';

const staggeredTransitionWrapper = componentData => 
    shallowMount(StaggeredTransition, {
      ...componentData,
});

const staggeredTransition = staggeredTransitionWrapper();

describe('StaggeredTransition.vue', () => {
  it('should render a staggered transition component', () => {
    expect(staggeredTransition.element.tagName).toBe('SPAN');

    expect(staggeredTransition.html()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  it('should mock calling the enter method', () => {
    const enterMock = jest.fn();

    StaggeredTransition.methods.enter = enterMock;

    const staggeredTransitionWrapper2 = componentData => 
    shallowMount(StaggeredTransition, { ...componentData });

    const staggeredTransition2 = staggeredTransitionWrapper2({
       slots: {
       default: '<h1 :key="1">Staggered transition test</h1>',
      },
    });

    expect(enterMock).toBeCalled();
  });
});
```

Code for the StaggeredTransition component

```
  <template>
    <transition-group
      :tag="tag"
      :name="'staggered-' + type"
      :css="false"
      appear
      @before-enter="beforeEnter"
      @enter="enter"
      @leave="leave"
    >
      <slot />
   </transition-group>
</template>

<script>
const { log } = console;

export default {
  name: 'StaggeredTransition',

  props: {
    type: {
      type: String,
      options: ['fade', 'slide'],
      required: false,
      default: 'fade',
    },

    tag: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: 'div',
    },

    delay: {
      type: Number,
      required: false,
      default: 100,
    },
  },

  methods: {
    beforeEnter(el) {
      console.log('beforeEnter');
      el.classList.add(`staggered-${this.type}-item`);
    },

    enter(el, done) {
      console.log('enter');

      setTimeout(() => {
        el.classList.add(`staggered-${this.type}-item--visible`);
        done();
      }, this.getCalculatedDelay(el));
    },

    leave(el, done) {
      console.log('leave');

      setTimeout(() => {
        el.classList.remove(`staggered-${this.type}-item--visible`);
        done();
      }, this.getCalculatedDelay(el));
    },

    getCalculatedDelay(el) {
      console.log('getCalculatedDelay');

      if (typeof el.dataset.index === 'undefined') {
        log(
          'data-index attribute is not set. Please set it in order to 
make the staggered transition working.',
        );
      }

      return el.dataset.index * this.delay;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: More context of what the `StaggeredTransition` module looks like would help. Is it possible methods is a prototype property not a static property?

Comment: Thanks for your response, for sure it it could be a prototype property